# Exact quote (and source of) by John Conway regarding the action/origin of the Monster?

Tags: quote, group-theory, string-theory

I vaguely remember reading a quote/listening to a statement by John Conway which I can paraphrase as follows:

*"I do not know what object the Monster group acts on, but it seems to exist because string theory needs/wants/demands it."*

Unfortunately, I do not know whence, nor do I know the exact phrasing. Does anyone know of the quote to which I am referring, and perhaps has a reference?

Comment: Hi,  just letting you know that double-posting is frowned upon.  If a question is considered off-topic, the mods will 'migrate' it to the appropriate group

Comment: That’s fine, we’ll cross the bridge when we get to that.

Answer (score 1):

I found this statement in a short [IAS](https://www.ias.edu/ideas/2013/roberts-monster) article,

> In [Conway's] view, conformal field theory is too complicated to
>   understand, and thus too complicated to be the only answer.

However,  seeing as Conway's work on the Monster group and 'moonshine' seems to predate its proposed application to string theory by a number of years, I'm a bit skeptical that he would have made a statement like that.

Comment: Thank you. However this isn’t what I’m looking for. Also to comment on your doubt that Conway might have said something like this: the connection to string theory was known from the late 1980‘s. In fact it was his former PhD student, Richard Borcherds, who formalized the string theoretic GKM and a lot of work followed from a stringy POV. There have been almost 30 years in between for someone to make that statement. I can also assure you personally that Conway pondered about this a lot over the past few years but was in some sense resigned to finding out on what object the Monster acted on.

Comment: It is also categorically incorrect of you to assume that mathematicians, in this case Conway, do not think about open questions related to their research once they have worked on a problem.